# Save Contact 7 form queries to (abc.com) domain from (xyz.com) | Cross domain WordPress form saving

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Is it possible to configure Contact Form 7 on my main website (***[www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)***) in such a way that form queries submitted on (***[www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)***) can be saved to another domain's (***[www.abc.in](http://www.abc.in)***) WordPress Dashboard. If not possible, then what are the alternative ways?
Can I achieve the same result by using some other WordPress form plugin?

Comment: Yes. You can send data to www.abc.in by sending post request using api . That means you will accept contact 7 form data from user and send to www.abc.in by curl or guzzle technology

Comment: This sounds like a pretty specific use case, I rather doubt there will be contact form plugins available with that particular functionality. WordPress does have the `switch_to_blog` function to switch to using the tables of a different site in a multi-site setup - but you would have to hook into _all_ relevant parts of the CF7 plugin functionality. Plus, you'd need a hook at the end of every relevant method, to switch back - and I doubt those will actually exist.